# How to use variable inside interpolated string?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I'm trying to use a variable inside of an interpolated string, but not having much luck.  How would I do this?

```
var name = "mike";
var desc = "hello world {name}";
var t = $"{ desc }";
Console.WriteLine(t); // PRINTS: hello world {name}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Console.WriteLine(t); // PRINTS: hello world mike
```

Is this possible?

For example, suppose I have a method:

```
public string FormatString(string s) {
      var Now = DateTime.Now;
      return $s;
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(FormatString("The time is {Now}"));
```

Comment: is there no way of storing a variable (desc), and somehow have it interpreted based on contextual ambient variables?

Comment: @mjwlls, yup that's a duplicate - that's exactly what i'm trying to do

Comment: Since its not available within the C# language, does anyone know if there is a library? I know its been recommended to use CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync in the other answer, but I need to be able to pass in complex objects in the ambient context, not just string variables.

Comment: Actually, never mind.  CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync works for me, it supports complex global context parameters.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/c-6-string-interpolation-is-not-a-templating-engine-and-it-s-not-the-new-string-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `$`

```
var name = "mike";
var desc = $"hello world {name}"; // this needs be interpolated as well
var t = $"{desc}";
Console.WriteLine(t); // PRINTS: hello world mike
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[$ - string interpolation (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> **The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
>   string**. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
>   interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a
>   result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the
>   string representations of the expression results. This feature is
>   available in C# 6 and later versions of the language.

---

## Update

> but suppose I want to have a variable storing the string with {name}
>   in it. Is there no way to achieve interpolation if its in a variable?

No you would have to use standard `String.Format` Tokens

```
var tokenString = "Something {0}";

String.Format(tokenString,someVariable);
```

---

[String.Format Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the value of objects to strings based on the formats
>   specified and inserts them into another string.
>
> Use String.Format if you need to insert the value of an object,
>   variable, or expression into another string. For example, you can
>   insert the value of a Decimal value into a string to display it to the
>   user as a single string:

[Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The .NET composite formatting feature takes a list of objects and a
>   composite format string as input. A composite format string consists
>   of fixed text intermixed with indexed placeholders, called format
>   items, that correspond to the objects in the list. The formatting
>   operation yields a result string that consists of the original fixed text intermixed with the string representation of the objects in the list.

Comment: I'm trying to keep desc as a variable. i.e. suppose I want to pass in the string as a variable. Is there a way to interpolate the variable?

Comment: You have more details so I'll remove mine as it basically has the same. Looks like a dupe was found.

Comment: @Nkosi all good we answered it at the same time, its a sloooow day. Hence the excessive details

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, really appreciate it. It's too bad there isn't a way to do this using interpolated strings. I can probably do it with string.format, but it aint gonna be pretty